# Thymeleaf can't locate fragment in temporary directory in unit test

Tags: java, file, automated-tests, thymeleaf

In my current project I have a number of Thymeleaf fragments stored under the src tree `src/main/resources/templates/fragments`. In my test suite i have a number of test templates that will pull in individual fragments so that I may process them and compare the output with some test output files. These are located in `src/test/resources/test-templates/input` and look like the following:

**title-and-subtitle-test-input.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">>
<body>
<table 
        th:replace="~{fragments/titleAndSubtitle :: titleAndSubtitleTable(titleText = 'Test Title', subtitleText = 'Test Subtitle')}"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

and the titleAndSubtitle fragment looks like this:

**titleAndSubtitle.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<body>
    <table class="fragment" th:fragment="titleAndSubtitleTable(titleText, subtitleText)">
        <tr>
            <td class="title">[[${titleText}]]</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="subtitle">[[${subtitleText}]]</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

and my test thymeleaf config class looks as follows:

**ThymeleafTestConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
public class ThymeleafTestConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private static final String TEST_TEMPLATE_DIRECTORY = "classpath:/test-templates/input/";
    private static final String TEMPLATE_SUFFIX = ".html";

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    /**
     * THYMELEAF: View Resolver - implementation of Spring's ViewResolver
     * interface.
     *
     * @return ViewResolver
     */
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        return viewResolver;
    }

    /**
     * THYMELEAF: Template Engine (Spring4-specific version).
     *
     * @return SpringTemplateEngine
     */
    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        return templateEngine;
    }

    /**
     * THYMELEAF: Template Resolver for test templates.
     *
     * @return TemplateResolver
     */
    private ITemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix(TEST_TEMPLATE_DIRECTORY);
        templateResolver.setSuffix(TEMPLATE_SUFFIX);
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        templateResolver.setOrder(1);
        return templateResolver;
    }
}
```

I haven't been able to correctly  configure a Thymeleaf template resolver and engine to be able to locate the test input fiel and still resolve the fragment expression, i.e. pull in the fragment from the src tree. Instead I decided to copy the contents of my fragment directory in the src tree to a temporary folder - `src/test/resources/test-templates/input/fragments`, with the idea being that the fragments are placed in the test resource temporarily so the thymeleaf template resolver could successfully locate and retrieve them, pull them into the test template for processing, and once all tests have ran the temp directory would be deleted. I am able to successfully copy the directory and its contents to the test tree but I'm getting errors like :

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [test-templates/input//fragments/titleAndSubtitle.html]" - line 5, col 9)
//etc
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [test-templates/input/fragments/titleAndSubtitle.html] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

This is similar to the errors I was seeing when I was still messing around with template resolvers. The test looks as follows:

**FragmentTest.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ThymeleafTestConfiguration.class)
public class ClaimSnapshotFragmentTest {
    private static File sourceFragmentDirectory = new File("src/main/resources/templates/fragments");
    private static File tempFragmentDirectory = new File("src/test/resources/test-templates/input/fragments");

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setupClass() throws Exception {
        if(tempFragmentDirectory.exists()) {
            deleteDirectory(tempFragmentDirectory);
        } 

        copyDirectory(sourceFragmentDirectory, tempFragmentDirectory);
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void teardownClass() throws Exception {
        if(tempFragmentDirectory.exists()) {
            deleteDirectory(tempFragmentDirectory);
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    private SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine;

    @Test
    public void test_titleAndSubtitle_fragmentParsedWithData() throws Exception {
        final String expected = FileUtils.getFileFromFolderAsString("title-and-subtitle-test-expected-output.html", 
                FOLDER_TEST_TEMPLATES_OUTPUT);

        final String actual = templateEngine.process("title-and-subtitle-test-input", new Context());

        final Diff diff = DiffBuilder
                .compare(expected)
                .withTest(actual)
                .checkForSimilar()
                .normalizeWhitespace()
                .build();

        assertThat(diff.hasDifferences()).isFalse();
    }
```

Am I missing something with the Thymeleaf configuration? I have checked via code and manually that the fragments directory is created, contains the fragment template in question, and is successfully removed after the tests have ran but I'm still getting an error about files not existing. Note: I am using Thymeleaf version 3.0.9.RELEASE  with Thymeleaf layout dialect version 2.3.0. The application runs Thymeleaf in "offline mode" and is used primarily to create email bodies by combining data received by MQ and processing it in a template. The copyDirectory and deleteDirectory methods are from Apache Commons FileUtils class